# Print from within async Task

Tags: swift

I am experimenting with Swift on the server side and have come across a problem that I have also been seeing on the latest version of Xcode.

When doing `print` or `debugPrint` within an async Task block, the output doesn't appear:

```
@main
 18 struct PostgresTest {
 19   static func main() {
 20     print("Test print1")
 21     Task {
 22         print("Test print2")
 23 
 24         await TestPostgres.connectDisconnect()
 25     }
 26   }
 27 }
```

For the above code I can see "Test print1" appear on the terminal, however, the output from the second print doesn't appear.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I'm not familiar with server, but : Is `TestPostgres.connectDisconnect()` called or is the program/object deallocated before? Can you print in other threads that main (I think that's mandatory for macOS, not in iOS though).

Comment: can you confirm if `TestPostgres.connectDisconnect()` is being called? If not I probably know what's wrong

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your program is terminating before the Task completes. You need to await the Task. For example:

```
@main
struct PostgresTest {
    static func main() async {
        print("Test print1")
        await Task {
            print("Test print2")

            await TestPostgres.connectDisconnect()
        }.value
    }
}
```